# Sorting specific file in top most directory recursively

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for a way to identify the dist.xml files that are in the top most directory.

Example, I have this list of directory listing,

```
/opt/pictures/dist.xml
/opt/docs_old/dist.xml
/opt/public/dist.xml
/opt/documents/server/dist.xml
/opt/documents/dist.xml
/opt/documents/web/dist.xml
/opt/documents/class/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/1/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/2/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/3/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/4/dist.xml
/opt/documents/lessons/5/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/day/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/week/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/1/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/2/dist.xml
```

and I'm looking to have this output instead,

```
/opt/pictures/dist.xml
/opt/docs_old/dist.xml
/opt/public/dist.xml
/opt/documents/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/day/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/week/dist.xml
/opt/music/service/month/dist.xml
```

I'm trying to achieve this in JS. I thought a simple sort would work.

Comment: Can you show the code of the sort that you thought would work?

Comment: I don't have any code at the moment. Trying to think of an algo that could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort thes strings by the count of slashes and then by character and filter the array by having a look to seen pathes.

```js
var data = ['/opt/pictures/dist.xml', '/opt/docs_old/dist.xml', '/opt/public/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/server/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/web/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/class/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/1/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/2/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/3/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/4/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/5/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/day/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/week/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/1/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/2/dist.xml'],
    result = data
        .sort((a, b) =>
            a.replace(/[^\/]+/g, '').length - b.replace(/[^\/]+/g, '').length ||
            a > b || -(a < b)
        )
        .filter(
            (seen => s =>
                (parts =>
                    !parts.some((_, i, p) => seen.has(p.slice(0, i + 1).join('/'))) &&
                    seen.add(parts.join('/'))
                )
                (s.split('/').slice(0, -1))
            )
            (new Set)
        );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

No sorting needed. Put all the paths in a `Set`, then subsequently `filter` the array for those paths for which no ancestor exists in the set.

```js
var paths = ['/opt/pictures/dist.xml', '/opt/docs_old/dist.xml', '/opt/public/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/server/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/web/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/class/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/1/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/2/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/3/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/4/dist.xml', '/opt/documents/lessons/5/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/day/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/week/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/1/dist.xml', '/opt/music/service/month/2/dist.xml'];

const all = new Set(paths);
const result = paths.filter(path => {
    const parts = path.split("/");
    const filename = parts.pop();
    return !Array.from({length: parts.length}, (_, i) => i).some(i =>
        all.has(parts.slice(0, i).concat([filename]).join("/"))
    );
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey @Bergi do you know how this could be done in python3?

Comment: @d123 Yes, you can use the same approach in Python. Try it, then [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about your attempt.

Comment: any chance you could help me out? I'm still not able to figure out a way in Python3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61476824/python-identifying-only-files-in-top-most-directory